# Opensource software company and license obligation

Tags: gpl, bsd

There is a company that uses opensource code licensed by GPLv2 and BSD, they have a page in their site that specifies a contact mail to request the opensource code and a list of the used open source projects and their licenses; I've tried several times to request the source code by email to multiple email addresses of the company without success, they seem to be ignoring the request. What is their obligation about providing the opensource code in this situation? What law can help in this situation? What can I do in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the binaries?

Comment: yes, I do.....,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a legally obtained copy of some software that is under the GPL license, then you have a right to obtain the source code for that software.

However, in most cases you don't have any legal means to enforce that right yourself. If the company is not honoring their obligations under the GPL license, then only the copyright holder can take legal action against the company for violating the copyright license and thus infringing on the rights of the copyright holder.

If you know which portions of the software were provided to the company under the GPL license, you can inform the owners of those projects about the violation of their copyrights so that they can take appropriate action.
Apart from that, the only thing you can do is nicely ask the company for the source code or an explanation why they believe they don't have to give it to you. But if your earlier requests yielded nothing, don't expect too much.